# Get PC Username/Disk and use it to delete Files/Folders

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a program that with just one click at a button some files and folders will be deleted. The problem is that when I try to add more than one file/folder to delete it's not working, the code:

```
Private Sub LimparCache_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LimparCache.Click

    ' Declarando mensagens usadas nas caixas de texto
    Dim cache_encontrado = "Cache encontrado. Iniciando a limpeza!"
    Dim cache_nao_encontrado = "Cache não encontrado. Ele já está limpo!"
    Dim cache_limpo = "O cache do seu FiveM foi limpo com sucesso!"

    ' Encontrando arquivos
    If File.Exists("") Then
        MsgBox(cache_encontrado)
        ' Deletando arquivos
        File.Delete("C:\Users\PICHAU\Desktop\3.jpg")
        MsgBox(cache_limpo)
    Else
        ' Arquivos não encontrados
        MsgBox(cache_nao_encontrado)
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is in this line:

```
If File.Exists("") Then
```

If I jump a line and add other "*File.Exists*" the "*Then*" is not going to work. The other part of the problem is that I need to find the directory/folders in the Windows Users folder but when I add "*My.Computer.Name*" to the Directory it's not working too, the code:

```
If Directory.Exists("C:\Users\PICHAU\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache") Then
```

What I'm doing:

```
If Directory.Exists("C:\Users\My.Computer.Name\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache") Then
```

Is it possible to get the PC Disk too? Because I think it's not everyone that uses C disk.

Comment: [DriveInfo.GetDrives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: `dim cachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "FiveM\FiveM.app\cache") If Directory.Exists(cachePath) Then ...`. What is this: `If File.Exists("") Then ...` supposed to test? `My.Computer.Name` returns the name of the local machine, not the User (`Environment.UserName`) and you're using it as a string literal, not as a property value.

Comment: @Jimi The File.Exists was just a example. I want to check if two directorys exist and then delete both. Is it possible?

Comment: Using the `cachePath` value in the previous comment: `if Directory.Exists(cachePath) then Directory.Delete(cachePath, True) end if`. Verify with `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` that the directory you're about to delete is not the current, otherwise you get an exception. Use `SetCurrentDirectory()` to set another as current, eventually. The current User must have rights to delete that path and its content.